# Is there a way to integrate CommonJ WorkManager with JBoss 5.1

Tags: jboss5.x, commonj

I did find a Jboss Commonj Service on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jbosscommonj/), but that appears to be for JBoss 4x.
Any pointers would be great..

Answer (score 1):

Found that the following also works for JBoss 5 as well.

[link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jbosscommonj/)

Comment: can you please mention steps to integrate commonj into Jboss-5 ?